# Page redirection using Apache Camel

Tags: redirect, apache-camel

I am trying to develop a route that redirects a user from page1 to page2.

Route is triggered when user accesses the url :  http://localhost:8080/servlets/doSomething (page1)
and I want it to be redirected to http://google.com for instance (page2)

I have exposed a servlet in Camel :

in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>camelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>camelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in  camel context :

```
<camel:from uri="servlet://doSomething?servletName=camelServlet" />
```

I have tried to redirect using :

```
<camel:to uri="http://google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
```

But got java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 2):

Simply send and appropriate [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)  and put the URL you want to redirect to in the HTTP header "Location".

In Camel Java, this should be something like this :

```
from("servlet://doSomething?servletName=camelServlet")
    .setHeader("Location", simple("http://www.google.com"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 302);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still getting the exception : java.net.ConnectException

Comment: Which part is getting the exception ? The browser ?

Comment: And of course, remove the <camel:to uri="http://google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true" />. Camel should reply autmatically ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this proxy route:

```
    <route id="ProxyRoute">
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/servlets/doSomething?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;continuationTimeout=900000&amp;httpClient.timeout=900000"/>
        <to uri="jetty:http://google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false&amp;continuationTimeout=900000&amp;httpClient.timeout=900000"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very simple example:**

```
public void redirectFromSuccess(Exchange exchange) {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")); 
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,"http://www.google.com");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,"301");
}
```